# Set umask for systemd unit

Tags: systemd, umask

I am running `rsync` daemon with a specific user on Ubuntu machine. The problem is that since daemon users don't login, the `umask` set for the user is the default one.

How do I set `umask` for the user in the daemon process?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a [UMask=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#UMask=) directive in the `[Service]` section. Note that it's really *UMask*, with a capital *M*.